# Faster way to find duplicate SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, optimization

I have a query to get duplicate data with some extra condition but I feel that it is not fast enough. Any solution to make this query faster?

`v_listing` contains big information

```
SELECT DISTINCT  code, name, comm, address, area 
FROM v_listing t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                FROM v_listing t2
                WHERE t1.comm = t2.comm
                AND t1.address = t2.address
                AND t1.area = t2.area
                AND (t1.code > t2.code OR t1.code < t2.code))
ORDER BY comm, address, area
```

Comment: What is the view definition please? A view is just a macro and it expands out in queries.

Comment: v_listing is the combination of multiple table, but what I want to know if we can improve this sql without touch the view.

Comment: How slow is your query? On what amount of data did you run it?

Answer (score 3):

An `exists` clause does a semi-join, which isn't the most optimal way to compare two very large tables. In this case, it's one table, but the point stands. What you want to do is an `inner join`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    t1.code, 
    t1.name, 
    t1.comm, 
    t1.address, 
    t1.area 
FROM 
    v_listing t1
    inner join v_listing t2 on
        t1.comm = t2.comm
        AND t1.address = t2.address
        AND t1.area = t2.area
        AND t1.code <> t2.code
ORDER BY t1.comm, t1.address, t1.area
```

Also ensure that you have indexes on all of the join columns. That will speed things up tremendously, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well this one change alone should help a lot:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code, name, comm, address, area
FROM v_listing t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
        FROM v_listing t2
            WHERE t1.comm = t2.comm
            AND t1.address = t2.address
            AND t1.area = t2.area
            AND t1.code <> t2.code)
ORDER BY comm, address, area
```

Alternatively, you could do it like this:

```
SELECT comm, address, area, MIN(code), MAX(code), MIN(name), COUNT(*)
FROM v_listing t1
GROUP BY comm, address, area
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
ORDER BY comm, address, area
```

Comment: I'd advise against the second way. `min(code)` and `min(name)` most likely don't always go together on the same row.

Comment: I never implied that they were, the original question was somewhat unspecific on it's requirements.